# Parse XML data into a pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I want to transform my XML file into a dataframe pandas I tried this code

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/essai/dataXml.xml", "r"),"xml")

d = {}
for tag in soup.RECORDING.find_all(recursive=False):
    
    d[tag.name] = tag.get_text(strip=True)
df = pd.DataFrame([d])
print(df)
```

and this is a portion of my XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sentences>
    <sentence>
        <text>We went again and sat at the bar this time, I had 5 pints of guinness and not one buy-back, I ordered a basket of onion rings and there were about 5 in the basket, the rest was filled with crumbs, the chili was not even edible.</text>
        <aspectCategories>
            <aspectCategory category="place" polarity="neutral"/>
            <aspectCategory category="food" polarity="negative"/>
        </aspectCategories>
    </sentence>
</sentences>`
```

and I got this error

```
for tag in soup.RECORDING.find_all(recursive=False):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

How can I fix it?

and thank you in advance

edit:
replacing `soup.RECORDING.find_all` with `soup.find_all` fixed the error but still I don't get what I want

I want something like this
[image]

Comment: Why did you do `soup.RECORDING.find_all` instead of just `soup.find_all`?

Comment: I'm just a beginner :(  soup.find_all fixed the error but still I didn't get wat I wanted

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output to the question? I'll help you if so :)

Comment: actually, I don't know if a dataframe is the solution maybe I need to use a dict, what I need is to manage this data using python thank you in advance

Comment: Ok, it doesn't matter. Just show the output you expect

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: please see my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```py
d = {
    'text': [],
    'aspect': [],
    'polarity': []
}

for sentence in soup.find_all('sentence'):
    text = sentence.find('text').text
    for ac in sentence.find_all('aspectCategory'):
        d['text'].append(text)
        d['aspect'].append(ac.get('category'))
        d['polarity'].append(ac.get('category'))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                text aspect polarity
0  We went again and sat at the bar this time, I ...  place    place
1  We went again and sat at the bar this time, I ...   food     food
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the *new* pandas 1.3.0 method, [**`read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html), but `join` two calls for the different level of nodes. Default `parser` is `lxml` but can use the built-in `etree` to avoid the third-party XML package.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xml_file = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/essai/dataXml.xml"
doc = et.parse(xml_file)

df_list = [
    (pd.read_xml(xml_file, xpath=f".//sentence[{i}]", parser="etree")
       .join(pd.read_xml(
           xml_file,
           xpath=f".//sentence[{i}]/aspectCategories/*", 
           parser="etree"
       ))
    ) for i, s in enumerate(doc.iterfind(".//sentence"), start=1)
]

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```